# sharing the information between two iOS application in test

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing a test case which will launch a 3rd party app from my application using the bundle identifier. In my test case i want to get the data from the 3rd party application and validate against my expected result. Is there any way to get that data?

NOTE: I am launching a Virtual Machine using this 3rd party app and typing some information in some text editor (inside VM). I need that data for validation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood correctly your question but maybe this helps:
The ideal way to test this data would be testing the method (or whatever you are using) where you are receiving this data. I.e:

```
func processDataFromXXX(_data: Data) {
    // return or doing some stuff
}
```

So your unit test would be against `processDataFromXXX`, asserting that it is behaving as expected.
This way you also have the chance to mock your data so no need to open this third party app.

Answer (score 0):

Applications on iOS work in sandbox, and can't send data to each other.
I think you can use [Application Group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412643-containerurl) to send data between two applications. Any application from the same group can write and read from shared directory.
Also you can use a server to [send data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) from first application to the server and read data in the second application from the server.